# Unable to resume from sleep on raspberry pi when running full screen javafx app

Tags: java, javafx, gluon

I am using a Raspberry Pi 3 with JavaFX 8 Embedded (from Gluon) and the official 7" touch screen. When my app is running and the screen goes black (for power save), then I cannot wake it up again.

Touching the screen does not help, nor typing on the USB connected keyboard.
I have to SSH to the pi, kill my app, and then I can just touch the screen to have it wake up.

Any idea what might cause this?

Comment: Please provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example.

Comment: @AdamRen Any JavaFX program has it. The simplest that I tried it with is the "HelloWorld" sample from https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/samples

Comment: If every program experiences this issue then it should be a hardware or software, not a programming problem and thus I cannot help you.

Comment: Very helpful, Politic.  Check my answer below and see if it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you're running your JavaFX app via the command line (and not via an OS UI), then this solution solved my problems: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8056/disable-screen-blanking-on-text-console?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Stealing from that post's solution, the kernel controls console blanking, where you can check the duration the kernel uses for virtual console blanking via:

```
$ cat /sys/module/kernel/parameters/consoleblank
600
```

You can change that value by entering the following command in the console.

```
$ setterm -blank VALUE
```

Where the new VALUE is specified in minutes. A value of 0 disables blanking (which it sounds like is what you're after).

If you're like me, you could also make this change by editing /boot/cmdline and adding the following to the end of the line in that file

```
consoleblank=0
```